# Insert custom postmeta when custom post type published

Tags: actions, wpdb

I'm trying to populate the postmeta table with a custom value when a custom type ('my-solutions') is published.  I've read a few threads, the Codex and [Pippin's blog](http://www.wphub.com/run-a-function-when-post-published) on this matter and tried many variations, but can't get this to work.  If anyone can add or correct anything that would be great.

```
function run_when_my_solution_published( $post ){
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type == 'my-solutions'){
        $wpdb->insert('wp_postmeta', array( 'meta_id'     => NULL       ,
                                            'post_id'     => $id        ,
                                            'meta_key'    => 'my_json'  ,
                                            'meta_value'  => 'json'     ),
                                     array( '%d' , '%d' , '%s' , '%s' )
        );


    }
}
add_action('new_to_publish', 'run_when_my_solution_published');
```

Comment: Could you check the `$post->post_status` whenever a post is saved to see if it's published? There also seems to be a [Publish Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) hook "**That's not deprecated!**".

Comment: Thanks for the bold note, I don't see a deprecated notice at http://codex.wordpress.org/%20Post_Status_Transitions . . . nevertheless, I've tried that 'publish_post' action and it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Newer New solution:

```
function wpse153622_transition_solution( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status != $old_status && 'publish' === $new_status && 'my-solution' === $post->post_type ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_json', 'json' );
    }
}
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'wpse153622_transition_solution', 10, 3 );
```

This should trigger only when 1. the new post status isn't the same as the old one 2. new post status is equal to publish and 3. post type is equal to your post type.

### New Solution

Edit: After reading up on post status transitions, I think this should do the trick:

```
function wpse153622_save_solution( $post_id, $post ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_json', 'json' );
}
add_action(  'publish_my-solution',  'wpse153622_save_solution', 10, 2 );
```

This uses `publish_my-solution`, which should only trigger whenever a post of type `my-solution` is published.  See `{status}_{post_type}` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

### Old solution

Using the `save_post_{post_type}` action will the job for you, though it'll be called whenever you update the post as well as publish:

```
function wpse153622_save_solution( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_json', 'json' );
}
add_action( 'save_post_my-solution', 'wpse153622_save_solution', 10, 3 );
```

I've used this before and it works, but like I said, it'll be called whenever you make changes to the post.  I don't think that'll be much of an issue, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I only want to add the data on first publication. I've tried `new_to_publish_my-solution`, `publish_post_my-solution`, `publish_post`, and others, but the only action I can get to fire so far is `transition_post_status` (I'm checking by sending a die() command).  However I still can't get it to `add_post_meta to the $post->ID`

Comment: Added a new solution above the old one.  This one does work.  Just tested

Comment: Well the new solution will at least fire on Publish (with a die() command). Now if I could just get it to update the postmeta.

Comment: I've tested it with `post` as well as with other post types.  It adds the post meta, as you wanted

Comment: Thanks again, still all these actions tend to fire on any save of the post. Even though the documentation clearly says it shouldn't, it is firing all the time.  `publish_my-solution`

Comment: I think its because publish_my-solution gets called whenever it gets changed to publish, even if its from publish.  I'm gonna do some research on the most common transitions and make the proper changes

Comment: Newer new solution.

Comment: The codex seems to be just plain wrong about some of the POST TRANSITION STATUS hooks.  `publish` and `new_to_publish` will work on both publish and save (which seems to contradict the codex).  The only one that reliably worked only on initial publication is the `transition_post_status` with additional checks as per the marked answer supplied by Manny.  Perhaps newer versions of Wordpress are more in line with the codex as this website I'm working on is at 3.5.x

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add / remove terms from a post type if it was published by using the `transition_post_status` hook. I've adapted your question to my solution below:

```
function run_when_my_solution_published( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if($post->post_type == 'my-solutions' && $new_status == 'publish'){
        $wpdb->insert('wp_postmeta', array( 'meta_id'     => NULL       ,
                                            'post_id'     => $id        ,
                                            'meta_key'    => 'my_json'  ,
                                            'meta_value'  => 'json'     ),
                                     array( '%d' , '%d' , '%s' , '%s' )
        );
    }
}
add_action ('transition_post_status', 'run_when_my_solution_published', 999, 3);
```

Though [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_transition_post_status) says that it's not acceptable to use this hook, it was the only one I could get acutally working.

Comment: Actually the http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions page says this is acceptable (not to be confused with the private function `_transition_post_status`.  And the action fires, only it fires on every save of the post, not just intial publication.

Answer (score 0):

As @Howdy_McGee has said, I'd actually use the `publish_post` [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) instead.

Sample code block to send an email on publish:

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
    $edit = get_edit_post_link( $author, '' );
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

You can use more or less what you've already used here for filtering by `post_type`. I would also definitely recommend using the `add_post_meta` [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) instead of a custom `$wpdb` query.

Comment: I'm not against publish_action or add_post_meta if it would work. I've changed both of those and it still doesn't add the meta value to the database

Comment: Why not use `save_post_my-solutions`?